# Использование addToBackStack()

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Я правильно понимаю, что вызов `addToBackStack()` нужен только для отката изменений по кнопке `Назад`?

Сейчас читаю книгу Девида Гриффитса "Программирование под Android". И там он показывает пример кода для создания вложенных фрагментов

```java
StopwatchFragment stopwatch = new StopwatchFragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.stopwatch_container, stopwatch);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Использование `getChildFragmentManager()` он мотивирует тем, что нужна вложенная транзакция, которая не должна откатываться по кнопке `Назад`, а должна откатываться вся родительская транзакция.

Вопрос: если мы не планируем откатывать транзакцию, то зачем тогда вызывать `addToBackStack`? И второй вопрос. Изменится ли поведение программы если написать так:

```java
StopwatchFragment stopwatch = new StopwatchFragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.stopwatch_container, stopwatch);
ft.commit();
```

Т.е. мы заменили `getChildFragmentManager()` на `getFragmentManager()` и убрали `addToBackStack`

Comment: Забудьте про транзакции с фрагментами, Google уже выкинул все это в мусорную корзину, всем рекомендовано переходить на [Jetpack Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation)

Comment: @Barmaley спасибо за ценное замечание. Тяжело учиться, когда книги так быстро устаревают. Я учту рекомендацию. Но для общего развития хотелось бы услышать ответ на вопрос.

Comment: Работают же фрагменты нормально

Comment: @ArtyMorris, они и останутся работать. Только напрямую их уже дергать не надо, все через Navigation.

Answer (score 0):

1. `addToBackStack()` нужен для информирования контейнера о том, куда идти в случае отката по кнопке *Back*. API фрагментов не содержит встроенной поддержки навигации по кнопке *Back* (в отличие от `Activity`, которые поддерживают эту кнопку), поэтому есть такой костыль `addToBackStack()`
2. В вашем 2-м коде поведение конечно изменится, по кнопке назад вы не вернетесь в фрагмент

**P.S.** Как уже было написано в комментариях, не теряйте времени на изучение этого уже древнего API, переходите на [Jetpack Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation)

Comment: Еще раз: фрагмент **вложенный** в другой фрагмент. И я так и не понял, зачем при создании этого вложенного фрагмента из основного вставлять addToBackStack, если нам нужно откатить **родительский** фрагмент.

Comment: В первом случае откатится родительский фрагмент, во втором только StopwatchFragment. Это насколько я все помню. Не стоит уже на такие детали время тратить, вам правильно тут советуют :)